# react native new project cant run android from vs code terminal

Tags: react-native

i created a new project and run

```
npx react-native run-android
```

command in visual studio code terminal. but i got an error

```
 What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
```

[image]

but i can build the app with the same command in using iterm

what is difference? cause idk what changed and. i didnt changed anything

Comment: run it via Android studio once.

Comment: @ShahanshahAlam i tried that too. build the project with android studio than i tried npx react-native run-android command but same problem come again